# Overriding property setter from parent class

Tags: objective-c, properties

I don't seem to find the answer to this one.

In a base class I define this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger foo;
```

And have a custom setter

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSInteger)foo {
    _foo = foo;
    // Do some stuff...
    [self sayHello];
}
```

So far so good!. Now I have a derived class, and try to override the property setter

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSInteger)foo {
    _foo = foo + 1;
    // Do some different stuff...
    // but avoid calling [self sayHello];
}
```

the compiler says `Use of undeclared identifier _foo` on the derived class' implementation.
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance variable `_foo` is private to the implementation of your base class so it cannot be accessed in subclasses.
However there are workarounds:
You can store foo as a protected instance variable and then access it directly from subclasses:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
{
    @protected NSInteger _foo;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger foo;
@end
```